# Tensorflow Object detection custom data set

Tags: python, tensorflow

An error occurred when I am trying to test tensorflow object detection API using their own guide at [Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md) I got the following error when running test script mentioned in their guide

> python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
>   /home/appu/anaconda3/envs/ml/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
>     return f(*args, **kwds)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 21, in 
>       from object_detection.builders import model_builder
>     File "/home/appu/RD/ml/models/research/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 19, in 
>       from object_detection.builders import box_predictor_builder
>     File "/home/appu/RD/ml/models/research/object_detection/builders/box_predictor_builder.py", line 18, in 
>       from object_detection.predictors import convolutional_box_predictor
>     File "/home/appu/RD/ml/models/research/object_detection/predictors/convolutional_box_predictor.py", line 18, in 
>       from object_detection.core import box_predictor
>     File "/home/appu/RD/ml/models/research/object_detection/core/box_predictor.py", line 137, in 
>       class KerasBoxPredictor(tf.keras.Model):
>   AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras' has no attribute 'Model'

I am using python 3.6 and tensorflow version 1.4 and my full package list is given below

```
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

_tflow_190_select         0.0.3                       mkl  
absl-py                   0.3.0                    py36_0  
appdirs                   1.4.3            py36h28b3542_0  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0  
astor                     0.7.1                    py36_0  
astroid                   1.6.5                    py36_0  
attrs                     18.1.0                   py36_0  
automat                   0.7.0                    py36_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    2.1.3                    py36_0  
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
cachetools                2.1.0                     <pip>
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0  
cffi                      1.11.5           py36h9745a5d_0  
constantly                15.1.0           py36h28b3542_0  
contextlib2               0.5.5                    py36_0  
cryptography              2.2.2            py36h14c3975_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py36_0  
cython                    0.28.4           py36hf484d3e_0  
dbus                      1.13.2               h714fa37_1  
decorator                 4.3.0                    py36_0  
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py36_2  
expat                     2.2.5                he0dffb1_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h9420a91_0  
freetype                  2.9.1                h8a8886c_0  
funcsigs                  1.0.2                    py36_0  
gast                      0.2.0                    py36_0  
glib                      2.56.1               h000015b_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                h6c8ec71_1  
google-api-core           1.3.0                     <pip>
google-api-python-client  1.7.4                     <pip>
google-auth               1.5.1                     <pip>
google-auth-httplib2      0.0.3                     <pip>
google-cloud-bigquery     1.5.0                     <pip>
google-cloud-core         0.28.1                    <pip>
google-resumable-media    0.3.1                     <pip>
googleapis-common-protos  1.5.3                     <pip>
grpcio                    1.12.1           py36hdbcaa40_0  
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               hbbd80ab_1  
gstreamer                 1.14.0               hb453b48_1  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py36_0  
httplib2                  0.11.3                    <pip>
hyperlink                 18.0.0                   py36_0  
icu                       58.2                 h9c2bf20_1  
idna                      2.7                      py36_0  
incremental               17.5.0                   py36_0  
intel-openmp              2018.0.3                      0  
ipykernel                 4.8.2                    py36_0  
ipython                   6.5.0                    py36_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0  
ipywidgets                7.3.1                    py36_0  
isort                     4.3.4                    py36_0  
jedi                      0.12.1                   py36_0  
jinja2                    2.10                     py36_0  
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py36_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_4  
jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py36_0  
jupyter_console           5.2.0                    py36_1  
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py36_0  
kaggle                    1.4.5                     <pip>
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36hf484d3e_0  
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36h14c3975_2  
lcms                      1.19                          0  
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 7.2.0                hdf63c60_3  
libgfortran-ng            7.2.0                hdf63c60_3  
libpng                    1.6.34               hb9fc6fc_0  
libprotobuf               3.5.2                h6f1eeef_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h1bed415_0  
libstdcxx-ng              7.2.0                hdf63c60_3  
libtiff                   4.0.9                he85c1e1_1  
libuuid                   1.0.3                h1bed415_2  
libxcb                    1.13                 h1bed415_1  
libxml2                   2.9.8                h26e45fe_1  
libxslt                   1.1.32               h1312cb7_0  
lxml                      4.2.3            py36hf71bdeb_0  
markdown                  2.6.11                   py36_0  
markupsafe                1.0              py36h14c3975_1  
matplotlib                2.2.2            py36hb69df0a_2  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py36_1  
mistune                   0.8.3            py36h14c3975_1  
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1  
mkl_fft                   1.0.4            py36h4414c95_1  
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h4414c95_1  
mock                      2.0.0                    py36_0  
nbconvert                 5.3.1                    py36_0  
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py36_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  hf484d3e_0  
notebook                  5.6.0                    py36_0  
numpy                     1.15.0           py36h1b885b7_0  
numpy-base                1.15.0           py36h3dfced4_0  
oauth2client              4.1.2                     <pip>
object-detection          0.1                       <pip>
olefile                   0.45.1                   py36_0  
openssl                   1.0.2o               h14c3975_1  
pandas                    0.23.3                    <pip>
pandoc                    2.2.1                h629c226_0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py36_1  
parso                     0.3.1                    py36_0  
pbr                       4.2.0                    py36_0  
pcre                      8.42                 h439df22_0  
pexpect                   4.6.0                    py36_0  
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py36_0  
pillow                    5.2.0            py36heded4f4_0  
pip                       18.0                      <pip>
pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0  
prometheus_client         0.3.1                    py36_0  
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15                   py36_0  
protobuf                  3.5.2            py36hf484d3e_1  
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py36_0  
py-cpuinfo                4.0.0                     <pip>
pyasn1                    0.4.4                    py36_0  
pyasn1-modules            0.2.2                    py36_0  
pycparser                 2.18                     py36_1  
pygments                  2.2.0                    py36_0  
PyHamcrest                1.9.0                     <pip>
pylint                    1.9.2                    py36_0  
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py36_0  
pyparsing                 2.2.0                    py36_1  
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h22d08a2_0  
python                    3.6.6                hc3d631a_0  
python-dateutil           2.7.3                    py36_0  
pytz                      2018.5                   py36_0  
pyzmq                     17.0.0           py36h14c3975_3  
qt                        5.9.6                h52aff34_0  
qtconsole                 4.3.1                    py36_0  
readline                  7.0                  ha6073c6_4  
rsa                       3.4.2                     <pip>
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0  
service_identity          17.0.0           py36h28b3542_0  
setuptools                39.2.0                   py36_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py36_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py36hf484d3e_0  
six                       1.11.0                   py36_1  
sqlite                    3.24.0               h84994c4_0  
tensorboard               1.9.0            py36hf484d3e_0  
tensorflow                1.9.0           mkl_py36h6d6ce78_1  
tensorflow-base           1.9.0           mkl_py36h2ca6a6a_0  
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py36_1  
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1  
testpath                  0.3.1                    py36_0  
tk                        8.6.7                hc745277_3  
tornado                   5.0.2            py36h14c3975_0  
tqdm                      4.24.0                    <pip>
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py36_0  
twisted                   18.7.0           py36h14c3975_1  
uritemplate               3.0.0                     <pip>
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py36_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_1  
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0  
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.3.1                    py36_0  
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36h14c3975_2  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
zeromq                    4.2.5                hf484d3e_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               ha838bed_2  
zope                      1.0                      py36_0  
zope.interface            4.5.0            py36h14c3975_0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just resolved the issue by upgrading my tensorflow to 1.9.0